# Yii checkbox in dropdown

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I'm developing app with `Yii` framework. I need from dropdown list with checkboxes as values of this list. I've been searching about this but didn't find anything. Can someone help me with this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the link to a Yii extension which does exactly what you want!

[Yii Framework Extension: echmultiselect](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/echmultiselect/)

On top of that, there are other Yii extensions for multiselect features that are also quite interesting! you might also want to take a look at these as well!

[Yii Framework Extension: Select2](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/select2/)

[Yii Framework Extension: emuliselect](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/emultiselect)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this (in this example your model must have a public field $availableLanguages):

```
<?= $yourActiveForm->field($model, 'availableLanguages', ['template' => "
<div class='dropdown'>
    <button
    class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle'
    data-toggle='dropdown'
    type='button'>
        <span>Select languages</span>
        <span class='caret'></span>
    </button>
    {input}
</div>"])->checkboxList(
[
    'FR'=>'France',
    'DE'=>'Germany'
],
[
    'tag' => 'ul',
    'class' => 'dropdown-menu',
    'item' => function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
        return '<li>' . Html::checkbox($name, $checked, [
            'value' => $value,
            'label' => Html::encode($label),
        ]) . '</li>';
    }
]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple textbox and when the user clicks you display a list of checkboxes

```
<div id="listOfDays">
                        <span><?php echo Yii::t('frontend','CHOOSE_DAY'); ?> </span>
                        </div>
                        <div id="itemslistOfDays" style="display:none;position:absolute;z-index:10;background-color:white; width:300px">
                        <?php
                        echo $form->checkBoxList($model, 'freq_details', array(
                            '1'=>Yii::t('frontend','MONDAY'),
                            '2'=>Yii::t('frontend','TUESDAY'),
                            '3'=>Yii::t('frontend','WEDNESDAY'),
                            '4'=>Yii::t('frontend','THURSDAY'),
                            '5'=>Yii::t('frontend','FRIDAY'),
                            '6'=>Yii::t('frontend','SATURDAY'),
                            '7'=>Yii::t('frontend','SUNDAY'),                       
                            )); ?>

                        </div>
```

You will have to write some javascript or jquery in order to hide,show and bind click event